# WSO2 IS - Is there any rest or soap endpoints where we can update the challenge questions of a user

Tags: wso2-identity-server

we need to implement the "Update Challenge Questions of a user" functionality through WSO2 IS. We have an application UI from where post login, user can update his challenge questions as well as answers. I found that with the "setChallengeQuestionsOfUser" operation in the "UserIdentityManagementAdminService?wsdl", we can save the challenge questions and answers of a user. Do we have any operation for update scenario?
If i use the same operation, it saves the questions and answers to WSO2 IS for that user, but it does not remove old questions.

Answer (score 0):

No, update challenge question operation is not available via rest or soap endpoints.